# CSS selector for multiple label[for=name]

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Guess I have a list of items in a form where I want to select some labels and apply rules.

Currently I am doing that, which I believed should work according to the other selector rules,

```
#form-list-element label[for=strategy-clickAppend], label[for=strategy-fixedRedirect], label[for=strategy-iframe] 
{
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

But did not.

If someone out there ever had the same issue or know what I am missing, will be much appreciated.

Thanks for looking.

Solve:

I just solved my own problem without specifying the element spec in the css. So it looks like

```
label[for=strategy-notImplemented], label[for=strategy-implemented], label[for=strategy-noDesktop], label[for=strategy-desktop] 
{
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

While you wrote this:

```
#form-list-element label[for=strategy-clickAppend], 
label[for=strategy-fixedRedirect], 
label[for=strategy-iframe]
```

It's possible you meant this, which is more specific:

```
#form-list-element label[for=strategy-clickAppend], 
#form-list-element label[for=strategy-fixedRedirect], 
#form-list-element label[for=strategy-iframe]
```

If there are no other `strategy-xx` labels, you can make your selector simpler for modern browsers:

```
#form-list-element label[for^="strategy"] /* starts with "strategy" */
```

In either case, try adding quotes to your selectors:

```
label[for="strategy-fixedRedirect"]
```

Comment: But this means I have to write #form-list-element three times. I actually fixed by removing the element spec. So it looks like label[for=strategy-notImplemented], label[for=strategy-implemented], label[for=strategy-noDesktop], label[for=strategy-desktop] {
    font-weight: bold;
}

Comment: That's just how it works, you don't really have a choice without modifying your HTML.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with the selector `[attr*=""]`

```
#form-list-element label[for*="strategy"] {
    font-size:normal;
}
```

With this you're searching in the `for` string all items with the word `strategy`. Remember to wrap the `attr` in `"quotes"`.

A demo **http://jsfiddle.net/rP8g2/7/**

Comment: No I can not as there will be other list items with *strategy

Comment: If you have more items with "strategy" word then it will select all of them inside the element with id="form-list-elemet". Id is unique.

Comment: Exactly, thats why you cant use *strategy as the aim is to target specific elements instead of all.

Comment: And exactly how you define those specific elements??? "CSS selector for multiple label" your title

Comment: @Danko: By naming them one by one as he is already doing in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the full selector after each ,  try this:

```
#form-list-element label[for=strategy-clickAppend], 
#form-list-element label[for=strategy-fixedRedirect], 
#form-list-element label[for=strategy-iframe]{
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is a specificity issue, but if you're looking to target various labels specifically within your ID of "form-list-element", you'll need to repeat the ID selector before each label selector, like this:

```
#form-list-element label[for="strategy-clickAppend"],
#form-list-element label[for="strategy-fixedRedirect"],
... {
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's shorter too!

```
label[for=strategy-notImplemented], [for=strategy-implemented], [for=strategy-noDesktop], [for=strategy-desktop] 
{
    
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).